# Crear un procedimiento en una tabla que actualice otra tabla diferente

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy dándole vueltas al código que tengo planteado y soy consciente de que algunas dudas no se podrán resolver en el foro, pero tal vez otras sí.

He creado la siguiente tabla `tb_quarter`:

```
CREATE TABLE erp.tb_quarter (
    quarter integer NOT NULL,
    year integer NOT NULL,
    cust_no character(5) NOT NULL,
    iva_percent integer NOT NULL,
    amount real NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_quarter
        PRIMARY KEY (quarter, year),
    CONSTRAINT fk_quarter
        FOREIGN KEY (cust_no)       
        REFERENCES erp.tb_customer (cust_no)
);
```

Adicionalmente tengo otras 2 tabla más: `tb_customer`:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_customer(
    cust_no CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    cust_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    cust_cif VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    last_updated_by VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'SYSTEM',
    last_update_date DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_tb_customer PRIMARY KEY (cust_no)
);
```

y la otra tabla es `tb_invoice`

```
CREATE TABLE erp.tb_invoice (
    co_code            CHARACTER(3) NOT NULL,
    invoice_id         INT NOT NULL,
    invoice_no         CHARACTER VARYING(15)  NOT NULL,
    cust_no            CHARACTER(5) NOT NULL,
    site_id            INT NOT NULL,
    payed              CHARACTER(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    net_amount         REAL NOT NULL,
    iva_amount         REAL NOT NULL,
    tot_amount         REAL NOT NULL,
    last_updated_by    CHARACTER VARYING(20) DEFAULT 'SYSTEM',
    last_update_date   DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_invoice PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_invoice_company FOREIGN KEY (co_code) REFERENCES erp.tb_company (co_code),
    CONSTRAINT fk_invoice_customer FOREIGN KEY (cust_no) REFERENCES erp.tb_customer (cust_no),
    CONSTRAINT fk_invoice_site FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES erp.tb_site (site_id)  
  );
```

Quiero crear un procedimiento `pr_calc_quarter` que, a partir de un año y un trimestre (1,2,3,4), inserte registros en la tabla `tb_quarter` de todos los clientes, por cada tipo de iva que tenga este cliente.

Para ello, debo buscar todas las facturas de cada cliente, sumar los totales por tipo de IVA y con ello tendré el total por año, trimestre y tipo de IVA.

La estructura que tengo creada hasta el momento es la siguiente (indico mis dudas sobre el propio código):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_calc_quarter(integer, integer) 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'      
AS $$

DECLARE
    quarter_init INT;
    quarter_end INT;
    
BEGIN
    quarter_init := 3*(quarter -1) +1;
    quarter_end := quarter_end +2;
     

INSERT INTO erp.tb_quarter 
SELECT quarter, year, i.cust_no, CAST(c.iva_percent AS INT), SUM (c.total) AS amount
FROM erp.tb_invoice AS i INNER JOIN
    (SELECT l.invoice_id, ROUND(100*(l.iva_amount/l.net_amount)) AS iva,
        SUM(l.net_amount)+SUM(l.iva_amount) AS total
    FROM erp.tb_lines AS l)
    GROUP BY erp.tb_customer AS c
COMMIT;

END;
$$;
```

Tal y como lo tengo planteado hasta el momento, tengo más o menos claro cómo introducir los valores (year integer, quarter integer) en la tabla. --> `INSERT INTO`

También creo que está bien planteado cómo obtener el año y trimestre a partir de una fecha.

No veo claro, en cambio, cómo agrupar por tipo de iva y cómo seleccionar `iva_percent` y `amount` no siendo claves foráneas. Esta parte quizás sea más dificil de responder en el foro.

Gracias.

Comment: que son todas esas cosas en la tabla tb_quarter? no se que quiere decir que no son claves foraneas...

Comment: @gbianchi, por clave foránea me refiero a una columna de una tabla es común a otra tabla. Lo que indico en los primeros cuadros de texto es cómo he definido cada columna; nombre de la columna, tipo de variable, si acepta o no valores nulos y al final las que son claves primarias (columna que define una tabla) y claves foráneas. Puedo indicarlo de otra forma si lo prefieres también

Comment: a lo que me refiero, es que aunque no hayas definido claves foraneas explicitas, si que tenes claves... si creaste un quarter en tu nueva tabla, podes hacer join por ese campo nuevo sin ningun problema. Los joins no son solo para claves, es para cualquier cosa, siempre y cuando sean del mismo tipo (o transformables). Y te preguntaba que son todas esas cosas, porque a mi los nombres no me dicen nada... pero supongo que como dos campos se llaman igual, son lo mismo...

Comment: @gbianchi, perdona que no te haya entendido. Si se llaman igual, son lo mismo, correcto. Y con lo que me dices, me hace pensar que puedo relacionarlo con otra tabla. Edito la entrada con esta nueva información

Comment: @gbianchi, no sé si podrías echarme una mano con la respuesta que indiqué. Quizás la duda no ha quedado claramente formulada. Estoy algo atascado y por eso te pregunto directamente. Gracias

Comment: No se de que me hablas.. que respuesta?

Comment: @gbianchi, de las cuestiones que indicaste en esta entrada donde hice la consulta. No sé si sirvió de algo de cara a ver cómo puedo solucionar mi duda. Gracias

Comment: No se que me estas preguntando.. ya te dije que podias hacer los joins igual... cual es la duda?

Comment: @gbianchi, mi duda no tiene que ver con los joins la verdad, sino con la creación del procedimiento para que a partir de otras tablas, pueda rellenar una nueva que he creado. Para hacerlo, debo buscar todas las facturas de cada cliente e ir sumando los totales por tipo de iva, pero no sé si debo usar un ```for``` adicional a lo planteado, por ejemplo

Comment: ok... no tengo ni idea de eso.. deberia hacer un analisis completo de tu requirimiento, y no estoy para eso. Si tenes un problema concreto, te podemos ayudar.. pero en este caso es algo que logicamente tenes que probar, y si ahi tenes un problema te podemos ayudar...

Comment: @gbianchi, ok, gracias en todo caso